# Strange crash of an application

Tags: android, view, adapter

ALL,

I am experiencing very strange crash of my Android app.
Here is the code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convert, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convert;
    ImageView image = null;
    TextView name = null, price = null;
    if( row == null )
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate( resource, parent, false );
        image = (ImageView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_picture );
        name = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_name );
        price = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_price );
        row.setTag( products.get( position ) );
    }
    Product product = products.get( position );
    name.setText( product.getProduct_name() );
    image.setImageBitmap( product.getProduct_picture() );
    price.setText( String.valueOf( product.getProduct_price() ) );
    return row;
}
```

This list view has 3 rows. The first 2 are visible and there is no problem. However when I try to scroll to display a 3rd row the program crashes with the NULL pointer exception on the line "name.setText(...);"

I am running on my HTC phone, not an emulator.

Does anybody experienced something like this? How do you debug and fix it? Or maybe its an indicator that the phone is going bad?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listview reuses rows views on scrolling instead of creating new one. So, in scrolling, your "convert" will not null and you will not run "name = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_name )" and "name" will leaves null. So, when you later will try to set text into name, you will get NullReferenceException.

You should always init your widgets object by findViewById.

Change your code and it should works good:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convert, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convert;
    ImageView image = null;
    TextView name = null, price = null;
    if( row == null )
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate( resource, parent, false );
    }
    image = (ImageView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_picture );
    name = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_name );
    price = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_price );
    row.setTag( products.get( position ) );

    Product product = products.get( position );
    name.setText( product.getProduct_name() );
    image.setImageBitmap( product.getProduct_picture() );
    price.setText( String.valueOf( product.getProduct_price() ) );
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Obviously the code needs changed but can you elaborate on why/what needs changed so the OP understands the mistake?

Comment: Of course. Listview reuses your rows views on scrolling instead of creating new one. In this case your "convert" will not null and you will not run "name = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_name )" and "name" will leaves null. So, when you letter will try to set text into name, you will get NullReference

Comment: That's better but it would be even more helpful if you updated your answer with the explanation. It just makes it easier for the OP and others to read and understand the problem and why this fixes it. Code only answers are generally frowned upon :(

Comment: @Dimmerg that's better...now I can upvote you, also :) Although, I would make a suggestion, as the comment I left on another answer, using [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) is better than calling `findViewById(...)` everytime.

Comment: Viewholder is good pattern, but as we can see in code, he already used setTag for storing model object.

Comment: Right but that doesn't prevent needing to call `findViewById()` for every `View` on every row and that can make the list laggy. `ViewHolder` allows you to only inflate those `Views` once

Answer (score 3):

This makes perfect sense.

First you set `name` to null.
If `row` is null, then you you create a new row and get `name`, etc., which should work fine.

However, if `row` is not null (i.e. when `convertView` is not null), then `name` will never be set, and will thus be null when you reach `name.setText( product.getProduct_name() );`

Comment: Good explanation. To fix the problem I might suggest using [Viewholder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) and watching [Google I/O Turbo Charge your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) a little old but still worth watching

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
if( row == null ){
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate( resource, parent, false );
}

image = (ImageView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_picture );
name = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_name );
price = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.product_price );
row.setTag( products.get( position ) );
```

The reason for this change is that if your row is not null, you still need to tell your variables what objects they point to before you can use them, otherwise you will only setup your variables when you create a new row.